# What is wrong with this expression? "if (factorarray[x]%2 == 0 && factorarray[x]%3 ==0..."

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, long-double

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iomanip>


using namespace std;

class Project3
{
public:
    void factorcalc()
    {
        while (i<5000000){
            ++i;
            factor = prime/i;
            if (factor == (long long int)factor){
            //if (modf(primeoverthree, 0) == 0){
                cout << "Factor is: " << setprecision(12) << factor << endl;
                cout << "Denominator is: " << setprecision(12) << i << endl;

                ++x;
                factorarray[x] = factor;
            }
            else{/*empty else statement*/}
        }
    }
    void displayfactorresults ()
    {
        for (x=0; x<9; ++x)
            if (factorarray[x]%2 == 0 && factorarray[x]%3 == 0 && factorarray[x]%5 == 0 && factorarray[x]%7 == 0){
            cout << factorarray[x] << setprecision(12) << endl;
            }
    }
private:
    long double factor = 1;
    long double prime = 600851475143;
    long double i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    long double factorarray[9];
};


int main() {
    Project3 Pro3;
    Pro3.factorcalc();
    Pro3.displayfactorresults();

    return 0;
}
```

The code is in response to Project 3 on projecteuler.net. I am attempting to find the largest prime factor of 600851475143 using basic knowledge of c++ & common sense.

The error is occurring in the `void displayfactorresults` function.

The compiler outputs the error message:

> "invalid operands to binary expression 'long-double' & 'long-double'"

Comment: Make your `factorarray` and other numbers be `uint64_t` . Using floating point for this task is hopeless

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%` remainder operator can only be applied to integer operands.

`factorarray[x]` is of type `long double`, a floating-point type.

Either use the `fmod` function (watch out for rounding errors!) or convert the operands to an integer type.

Or, better yet, make `factorarray` an array of some sufficiently large integer type in the first place. You're already assuming that the values can be converted to `long long int`. Converting something to a desired type is usually not as good as using the desired type in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

`factorarray` is an array of doubles. You cannot use modulo (`%`) on `double`. Either convert it to an array of `int` or cast the array element before you use it `((int)factorarray[x]) % 2 == 0`

Comment: It may not be safe to assume that `factorarray[x]` can be converted to `int` without overflow.

Answer (score 1):

`factorarray[x] % 2 == 0` (double type % 2 == 0) makes no sense because the reminder would be never 0, and of course compiler wont allow to do so.